# Regex to allow negative values

Tags: javascript, regex

I am hoping to find someone here which can give me a hand with some regex I need to modify.

This regex is being used in JavaScript for some validation:

```
/^([A-Z]{3} [0-9]+\.[0-9]{1,2}(, )?)+$/
```

This will correctly validate the following values:

EUR 20.3, USD 9.0

GBP 8.8

I would like to modify the regex to also accept negative values such as:

EUR -20.3, USD -9.0

I thank you for your help :)

Regards
Gabriel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

surely just add in:

```
-?
```

which should optionally match '-'

```
/^([A-Z]{3} -?[0-9]+\.[0-9]{1,2}(, )?)+$/
```

Answer (score 1):

In the exact same way you check for the coma `,` but xith negative signe `-`

Try something like this `([A-Z]{3} -?[0-9]+.[0-9]{1,2},?)+`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
/^([A-Z]{3} -?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?,?)+$/
```

the decimal places are now optional

GBP -1, GBP -1.1 should be valid